# ffmpeg, i want to add text on video and at the same time also want to add logo image on the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add text and logo image on video at same time and i have both command, but i want to merge them into one command. i tried a lot but its not working
this command used for add logo

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "movie=e\:/logo.png [watermark];
>   [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]"-y output.mp4.

this command used for add text on video

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v
>   drawtext="fontfile=e\:/font/segoeui.ttf:text='Hello
>   World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=30:y=h/2:x=0"-y output.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the movie filter: that's a very old, unnecessary, and outdated workaround. Just add `logo.png` like any other input and join [simple filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) with a comma.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=text='Hello World'" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this one is working for me...ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=fontfile=e\\:/font/segoeui.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=30:y=h/2:x=0:enable='between(t,6,20)'" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4